В pytube при обращении к методу streams возвращается миллион ошибок
from pytube import YouTube
link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J0Aq44Pze-w"
yt = YouTube(link)
print(yt.streams)




Traceback (most recent call last):   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\Desktop\IT\python\test.py", line 6, in <module>
    print(yt.streams)
          ^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 296, in streams
    return StreamQuery(self.fmt_streams)
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 176, in fmt_streams
    stream_manifest = extract.apply_descrambler(self.streaming_data)
                                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 160, in streaming_data
    self.bypass_age_gate()   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\__main__.py", line 257, in bypass_age_gate
    innertube_response = innertube.player(self.video_id)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\innertube.py", line 448, in player
    return self._call_api(endpoint, query, self.base_data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\innertube.py", line 390, in _call_api
    response = request._execute_request(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytube\request.py", line 37, in _execute_request
    return urlopen(request, timeout=timeout)  # nosec
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 215, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 521, in open 
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 630, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 559, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 492, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^   File "c:\Users\LoneWolf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\urllib\request.py", line 639, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp) urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

